# Check if strings on an arraylist are the same?

Tags: java

CandidateList is a list that consists of names of candidates. And ballot is a  list of strings. I want to check if the first name on the ballot list is the same to any of the names on the candidateList. If not then I want to check the next string on ballot and see if that string is the same to any of the names on the candidateList. And etc...

```
/**
     * @param candidateList a list of candidate names
     * @return the name of the first choice candidate for this Ballot from those
     * in candidateList
     */
    public String firstChoiceFrom(ArrayList<String> candidateList) {

        String firstChoice = "";
        String candidate = "";
        for (int can = 0; can < candidateList.size(); can++) {

            String bal = ballot.get(can); // gets next ballot
            candidate = candidateList.get(can); // gets next candidate
             while (!candidate.equals(bal))
             {

             }
            //checks to see whether the first name on the ballot
            if (candidate.equals(bal)) {        
                return candidate;
            } 

        }
```

Comment: Can you have better format and be more clear about what you really want?

Comment: I have code I just feel like its way off.

Comment: @Name I do not think nobody judge you based on that. We are here to help. I feel if you can have a better grammar and post up what you have done with specific question, you will have better result

Comment: If a `Set`  meets your requirements and you're really wanting `list1 ∩ list2`, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: I added my code. If anyone knows what I can do that will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare two lists and keep only the common ones. Like you mentioned in one of your comments

> All I want to do is return the String that both lists have.

You can just do below:

```
list1.retainAll(list2); // This will keep all elements that matches list 2 and remove other
for(String word: list1)
{
System.out.println(word); //it will print all words in list 1
}
```

**Edit**: Answering your comment. Yes you can do it one by one, but its not recommended since lists have the function `retainAll`

Comparing one by one would be like this:

```
for(String word : list1) //for each string in list 1
{
    if list2.contains(word);  // if list2 has the string
    {
      list3.add(word);  // add it in new list
    }
}
```

Then you can print list 3 like shown above

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. Is there a way to check the first String on list1 and see if that is the same as any of the Strings on list2. If not then check the next string on list1 and see if that is the same as any of the strings on list2. And etc.

Comment: @Name That's essentially what an intersection is - envision `A == list1` and `B == list2` in this image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Set_intersection.svg - the resulting list after is `list1 ∩ list2`

Comment: @Name Updated the answer. Its the long way and extra work. Always use the functions provided since they essentially do the same work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do if a match is found?

```
for(String s : list1){
if(list2.contains(s)){
// set a flag and break
}
}
```

This block basically iterates list one check if the String is contained in list 2. The code can be improved based on what you want to achieve.

**Edit as per the requirement**

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add("1");
    list1.add("2");
    list1.add("3");

    List<String> list2= new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("11");
    list2.add("12");
    list2.add("3");

    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(list2);
    list3.retainAll(list1);
    System.out.println(list3);
    //if you dont mind replacing your initial list, then you can use
    list1.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All I want to do is return the String that both lists have.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to approach this is how you describe it:  for every ballot in your ballot box, if the ballot matches the candidate's name, then we want to return that.

If we don't find anything, return `null`.  Not much else that we could do, realistically.  Note that this doesn't cover duplicates (that is, there are two candidates that have the same name in the ballot box), although there is a simple modification that could be done to allow it to cover that case.

```
for(String ballot : ballotBox) {
    if (candidateList.contains(ballot)) {
        return ballot;
    }
}
return null;
```